# Как в php laravel ограничить контент записи?

Tags: php, laravel

```
@foreach($news_take as $item)
   <div>
      <p class="slide_pod">{{$item->$title}}</p>
      <p class="slide_cont"> {{$item->$content}}</p>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Как в php laravel ограничить контент записи? для слайдера хочу вывод сделать

Comment: `mb_substr( $item->content, 0, 300 )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## str_limit

В Laravel есть такой хелпер.

Ограничивает число символов в строке.

```
str_limit($value, $limit = 100, $end = '...')
```

Пример:

```
$value = str_limit('The PHP framework for web artisans.', 7);

// The PHP...
```